# Importing silverware utensil sets to Hong Kong

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, hong-kong

I am visiting my boyfriend and his family for Christmas holidays in Canada. I might be getting a silverware utensil sets like dinner forks, knives and spoons and a dinnerware set for my gift. Am I allowed to pack those in my luggage and bring them back to Hong Kong?

Comment: Are you asking whether you’re allowed to import them to Hong Kong, or whether they’ll let you on a plane with silverware in your carry-on?

Answer (score 15):

You are allowed to bring it back to Hong Kong, as import of silverware is not illegal in Hong Kong.

There are only four kinds of items that require any kind of tax or duty for Hong Kong:

- Liquor
- Tobacco
- Hydrocarbon Oil
- Methyl Alcohol

You can read more about it at [this page](https://www.customs.gov.hk/en/passenger_clearance/duty_free/index.html) at customs.gov.hk

You should pack this into your *checked luggage* as knives are not allowed in carry on luggage.

Comment: And even most liquor has a 0% duty rate. [The prices](https://www.customs.gov.hk/en/trade_facilitation/dutiable/types/index.html) are quite simple.